# Не кешируются статические файлы

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Добавил в **web.config** следующий код

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="10.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

В заголовках ответа получаю все равно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В **cache-control** стоит значение **no-cache**. Как включить кеширование статических файлов?